# difference in behavior of if else and ifelse within the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to perform a `for loop` to replace the `NA` values with zero in some columns of a `data.frame`. Here is an example of my data:

```
data <- structure(list(x1 = c(441, 457, 455, 475, 490, 547, 21, 17, 16, 
26), x2 = c(25, 28, 24, 20, 21, 28, 0, 1, 0, 1), x3 = c(3, 1, 
2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), x4 = c(0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0), x5 = c(1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Applying if else to the `for loop` works:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if(is.na(data[j,i])){
      data[j,i] = 0 
    } else {
      data[j,i] =  data[j,i]
    }
  }
}
```

But when I apply ifelse in the `for loop`, it doesn't work:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
      for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
        ifelse(is.na(data[j,i]), 0, data[j,i])
      }
}
```

Could someone help me understand the difference in the behavior of these functions? Much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign the result to something:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
      for (j in 1:nrow(data)) {
        data[j, i] <- ifelse(is.na(data[j,i]), 0, data[j,i])
      }
}
```

Note however, that using two `for loops` is not best practice in your case.
An immediate improvement would be the following:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
    data[, i] <- ifelse(is.na(data[ ,i]), 0, data[ ,i])
}
```

Even better: you can use the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- mutate(data, across(everything, ~if_else(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Cettt, I lacked attention.

Comment: when I try using the alternative of `tidyverse` I have an error presented, @Cettt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `replace` + `is.na` for efficiency

```
data <- replace(data,is.na(data),0)
```

such that

```
> data
    x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1  441 25  3  0  1
2  457 28  1  1  2
3  455 24  2  0  2
4  475 20  2  0  5
5  490 21  0  0  2
6  547 28  2  0  0
7   21  0  0  0  0
8   17  1  0  0  0
9   16  0  0  0  0
10  26  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: I always forget the  `replace` function